# LabVIEW and C++ DLL

Tags: c++, c, dll, dns, labview

I'm working on something that data passed between LabVIEW and DLL.
I wonder how do I implement a function that LabVIEW give a unique name in string to DLL and DLL return a pointer which point at a specific block of memory in according to the name.
In other word, it it just like a relationship between domain name and IP address in networking field. 
But "name" is user defined and I return the pointer which is dynamically allocated for the name at runtime. It means that the relationship is not predefined. There is no lookup table to follow.

Example:
int* Mydll(char* name);

I think it is something kind of "reference to pointer" in C++ but I am not so sure. If so, how do I implement?

Answer (score 0):

1. Drop a Call Library Node.
2. Configure the return type as "int32" or "int64" based on your platform bitness (LV does not handle raw pointers, but if your DLL returns a pointer, LV can hold onto the numeric value until you're ready to pass it to some other DLL call that knows how to handle it).
3. Add a parameter. Configure it to be of type "String" and set the passing method to "C String Pointer" and enable the "Constant" checkbox.

That will do it. You can drop this image directly on your block diagram (it's a VI snippet) to create such a node -- just configure the DLL and function name.

[image]

Comment: sorry, maybe my example is bad. But please allow me to explain my question more.your answer is nice, and it will be part of my implement. But the part I really want to know is the content in that DLL. Suppose I give "The Name" string to the DLL and get 0X00ff00ff (address which were programmatically generated) back. And then whenever I give the same string to DLL, it will return 0X00ff00ff which I used to generated for the string "The Name". Of course if I give another one string such as "The Name1", it returns another address which specially generated for "The Name1".

Comment: There are two possible ways for me to interpret your desire... and maybe neither one is the one you mean.

Comment: Option A) You want to create some sort of a hash value where you pass in a string and you get the same number value back out. Likewise, if you passed the number in you'd get the string back out.     Option B) You want LV to fix the address 0x00ff00ff to always point at the text "The Name" forever afterward and never reuse that memory address for another string, so you could continue to hold onto that string inside the DLL.       Is either of these what you're after?